# Double Integrals In Polar Coordinates with infinity boundaries

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-5x^2-5y^2+8xy} dxdy$. Hint $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$

The options are as follows:

- $\frac{\pi}{2}$
- $\frac{\pi}{3}$
- $\frac{\pi}{4}$
- $\frac{\pi}{5}$
- $\frac{\pi}{6}$
- $\frac{\pi}{8}$

**My attempt**:

$x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

limits: $0<\theta<2\pi$ and $-\infty<r<\infty$

The integral expression becomes:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-r^2(5-8\sin\theta\,  \cos\theta)} drd\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac {\sqrt{\pi}}{(5-8\sin\theta\,  \cos\theta)}d\theta$$

This evaluates to

Let $u = 5-8\sin\theta\,  \cos\theta = 5-4\sin(2\theta)$ hence $du = -8\cos(2\theta) d\theta$ and

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac {\sqrt{\pi}}{(5-8\sin\theta \, \cos\theta)}d\theta = \sqrt{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac {1}{u(-8\cos(2\theta))}du = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8\cos(2\theta)}.\ln(5-4\sin(2\theta)).$$

Applying the limits gives 0 as answer which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Hint: What does the graph of $5x^2 + 5y^2 - 8xy = R$ look like, when you fix the parameter $R$ ?

Comment: I don't really know.

Comment: Well, it's an ellipse, centered at the origin, with axes being $y=\pm x$. This can be proven from symmetry. Therefore, you could find a transformation for the variables to make the integral easier ...

Comment: you can also grind through this with normal polar coordinates, but you forgot the Jacobian in the change of variables

Comment: The trigonometric denominator should be square-rooted.

Comment: Also, you can't just integrate $1/u$ times a function of $\theta$ by integrating the $1/u$ only, because $u,\,\theta$ are dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting
$$
x=\frac{3u-v}{3\sqrt{2}},\quad y=\frac{3u+v}{3\sqrt{2}},
$$
the expression $-5(x^2+y^2)+8xy$ becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
-5(x^2+y^2)+8xy &=& -5\frac{9u^2-6uv+v^2+9u^2+6uv+v^2}{18}+8\frac{9u^2-v^2}{18}\\
&=&-5\frac{18u^2+2v^2}{18}+8\frac{9u^2-v^2}{18}\\
&=&-5\frac{9u^2+v^2}{9}+4\frac{9u^2-v^2}{9}\\
&=&\frac{(-45+36)u^2+(-5-4)v^2}{9}\\
&=&\frac{-9u^2-9v^2}{9}\\
&=&-(u^2+v^2)
\end{eqnarray}
The Jacobian matrix of the transformation
$$
\Phi:(u,v) \mapsto (x,y)=\left(\frac{3u-v}{3\sqrt{2}},\frac{3u+v}{3\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$
is
$$
J_\Phi(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It follows that
$$
\det(J_\Phi(u,v))=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}.
$$
Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5x^2-5y^2+8xy}dxdy&=&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3}e^{-u^2-v^2}dudv\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-v^2}du\right)\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\pi}\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{3}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: How do make the choice of x and y. Is there a guide, is it intuitive or is it by practice?

Comment: I graphed the equations 5(x^2+y^2)-8xy=a, with a>0, and noticed and it is an ellipse whose major axis is the line y=x, in other words it is obtained as a rptation by 45 degrees of an ellipse whose major axis the  x-axis